# PHP Dependency Injection for Child Classes

Tags: php, dependency-injection

I'm trying to figure out the best practices for dependency injection in PHP.

Question: Do I have to inject all dependencies of a subclass into the parent class?  I use the terms 'parent' and 'child' in terms of a composition relationship.

My hesitation is because I find myself giving the parent class all kinds of dependencies so that it can just pass them down to dependent child classes.

Edit:

Below is a more concrete example of what I'm talking about.  `MyClassA` does not need the database connection object or the logger.  `DoSomething` does need these objects, however.  What is the best way to get the database connection and logger to the `DoSomething` instance?  I don't want to use singleton objects or global objects for the sake of unit testing.  Also, this example only uses to classes.  What if there are 3 or 4 and the 3rd or 4th needs some object instance but the first 2 or 3 don't?  Does `MyClassA` just pass the object to the next, and so on?

```
class MyClassA {
  protected $_doSomethingObject;

  public function doSomething()
  {
    return $this->_doSomethingObject()->doSomethingElse();
  }

  public function setDoSomethingObject($doSomethingObject)
  {
    $this->_doSomethingObject = $doSomethingObject;
  }
}

class DoSomething {
  protected $_logger;
  protected $_db;

  public function doSomethingElse()
  {
     $this->_logger->info('Doing Something');
     $result = $this->_db->getSomeDataById();
     return $results;
  }

  public function setLogger($logger)
  {
     $this->_logger = $logger;
  }

  public function setDBConection($db)
  {
     $this->_db = $db;
  }
}
```

Is the best way the example I show below?  If so, then the best way is to work backwards so to speak...?

```
    $logger = new Logger();
    $db = new DBConnection();    

    $doSomething = new DoSomething();
    $doSomething->setLogger($logger);
    $doSomething->setDBConnection($db);

    $a = new MyClassA();
    $a->setDoSomething($doSomething);
```

Comment: In most cases, aren't these child objects injected into the parents? If so you'd first be injecting their dependencies before injecting those objects into the parent. Do you have any simple concrete examples?

Comment: I added some pseudo code to look at.  Thanks for the reply!

Comment: There is such a thing as **Law of Demeter**. Read about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If so, then the best way is to work backwards so to speak...?

Yes. As I mentioned in the comment, you set up the inner most objects first.

If an object create another object internally that isn't exposed, then it could pass along its injected objects if appropriate. For example:

```
class DoSomething {
// ...
  public function foo() {
    $foo = new Foo();
    $foo->setLogger($this->_logger);
    return $foo->bar();
  }
}
```

However, if that secret `Foo` object needed references to other things that `DoSomething` didn't have, then you've got design issues. If that happens you need to do whatever is appropriate:

- Inject a `foo` object into the parent object prior to calling `foo()`.
- Inject that dependency into the parent object prior to calling `foo()`.
- Add the dependency as a function argument.
- Refactor code into a better design that doesn't create that problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need only include the dependancies in the classes that are going to directly need them. Since the required/included files will be loaded whenever the base class loads, they will automatically be available to any child classes.